# How to ignore Class Attributes while debugging code.?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution where i do authorize the requests for controller actions. so if the request is not authenticated i take the user to the login page.

here every time when  i want to  test some functionality i am commenting out the Authorize attribute, because it takes me through the login process (which i want to avoid while i am in debug mode.)

i want to avoid [Authorize] Attribute actions when i am debugging the code.

```
 namespace Student.Controllers
        {
    // Avoid Authorize Attribute when in Debug mode.

            [Authorize]

            public class StudentController : AppController
            {
              }
        }
```

any ideas on how to avoid authorize while debugging (apart from commenting the line.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is to use [Conditional compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691099(v=vs.71).aspx), which is verbose, but still better than *find and comment* approach, like this

```
namespace Student.Controllers
{
    // Avoid Authorize Attribute when in Debug mode.
#if !DEBUG
    [Authorize]
#endif
    public class StudentController : AppController
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can write your own version of the `Authorize` attribute that checks for `Debugger.IsAttached` though.

The best thing you can do is to create a test environment with the authorizations you need. It will make developing a lot easier than fiddling around with custom attributes just for this goal.

Comment: I wish i could write my own authorize Attribute, but as of now  i have owin handling it. but yeah agree to your point on creating a test environment for this.(I will try in near future.)